# Updating Model Attributes Through Show Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, update-attributes

I am looking to allow a user to update a model's attributes through the model's show page, then submit, to display updated attributes. `:startdate` and `:enddate` are in my `attr_accesible` list for the `cart.rb` model. Based on the log it looks like it is taking the enddate and startdate but isn't setting it. Any thoughts? Thanks so much.

**carts_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
    if @cart.update_attributes(params[:cart])
      format.html { redirect_to(@cart, :notice => 'Dates Set.') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

**carts/show.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_for @cart do %>
       From <%= text_field_tag :startdate %> </br>
       To <%= text_field_tag :enddate %>
       <%= submit_tag "Set Dates", :method => :put %>
    <% end %> 

    Rental Dates: <%= @cart.startdate %> <%= @cart.enddate %>
```

**development.log**

```
Started POST "/carts/42" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-10 14:27:10 -0400
DEPRECATION WARNING: Setting filter_parameter_logging in ActionController 
is deprecated and has no longer effect, please set 'config.filter_parameters' 
in config/application.rb instead. (called from <class:ApplicationController> at
/Users/willdennis/rails_projects/spinlister/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8)
Processing by CartsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   
"authenticity_token"=>"2RC9jfvbdUWtlT3OWnVd1OhW7WigUPYVoS5Quuwv2hQ=", 
"startdate"=>"08/10/2011", "enddate"=>"08/18/2011", "commit"=>"Set Dates", "id"=>"42"}
 [1m[35mCart Load (1.1ms)[0m  SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE ("carts"."id" = 42)   
 LIMIT 1 Redirected to http://localhost:3000/carts/42 Completed 302 Found in 82ms


  Started GET "/carts/42" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-10 14:27:10 -0400
  DEPRECATION WARNING: Setting filter_parameter_logging in ActionController is       
  deprecated and has no longer effect, please set 'config.filter_parameters' in  
  config/application.rb instead. (called from <class:ApplicationController> at 
/Users/willdennis/rails_projects/spinlister/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:8)
   Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
   Parameters: {"id"=>"42"}
   [1m[36mCart Load (1.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE ("carts"."id" = 42) LIMIT 1[0m
   [1m[35mLineItem Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE ("line_items".cart_id = 42)
   [1m[36mBike Load (1.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "bikes".* FROM "bikes" WHERE ("bikes"."id" = 86) ORDER BY bikes.created_at DESC LIMIT 1[0m
```

Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (1.5ms)
       [1m[35mUser Load (2.4ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
       Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (116.3ms)
       Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.3ms)
       Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (398.2ms)
       Completed 200 OK in 431ms (Views: 399.6ms | ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)

```
   Started GET "/stylesheets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-10 14:27:11 -0400

   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/stylesheets/application.css"):


   Rendered /Users/willdennis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tut/gems/actionpack-  3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.3ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using `form_for` correctly. This is how the form should be generated:

```
<%= form_for @cart do |f| %>
  From <%= f.text_field :startdate %> <br>
  To <%= f.text_field :enddate %>
  <%= f.submit "Set Dates" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you don't need to use `:method` here

Comment: Thanks so much. That updates the page nicely. Do you know how I could preserve the calendar jQuery dropdown (which was triggered by the`text_field_tag` I believe)?

Comment: The element still looks the same, it just has a different ID. Simply adjust the jQuery selector and it should work.